# Is this argument for uniform continuity good?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Consider the function $f:(-\infty, 1)\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$. I would like to prove that this function is uniformly continuous.
My argument is as follows: the function is continous because it is the division of two continuous functions. Now, $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=0$, so we are done.
I want to make sure that this is a correct way of proving uniform continuity. I know that this works for functions defined on an interval that contains $\infty$, but I want to make sure that this also works for $-\infty$.
Furthermore, what if our function's domain is no longer an interval, but a union of intervals that contains $\infty$ or $-\infty$? Does the conclusion still hold?

Comment: The function is *not* uniformly continuous. The problem is near $x=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true. The problem here is not $-\infty$, the problem happens near the point $1$. For example, $1-\frac{1}{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence of elements in $(-\infty,1)$. However, $f(1-\frac{1}{n})=-n$ is clearly not a Cauchy sequence. So $f$ is not uniformly continuous. (otherwise it would map Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences)

Another way to see this: in general, if $a,b$ are real numbers (not $\infty$ or $-\infty$) and a function $f$ is uniformly continuous at $(a,b)$ then it can be extended to a continuous function $[a,b]$. However, your function can't be continuously extended to the point $x=1$, as the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-} f(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah, I see, so $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-} f(x)$ should have been finite too for my argument.

Comment: @TheZone Indeed (Also, your proof of continuity is missing something: what would break if we changed the domain to $\mathbb{R}$?)

Comment: Yes. If $b$ is finite then for $f$ to be uniformly continuous at $(-\infty, b)$, the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to b^-} f(x)$ must exist. This is not necessary if $b=\infty$ though.

Comment: @user3482749 well, we wouldn't be able to define that function on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Mark Thanks, now I get it. Are there similar results if our domain in the union of some intervals?

Comment: @TheZone Sure, but your argument doesn't use anything that would avoid that problem. You've just said "every quotient of continuous functions is continuous", and that's just not true.

Comment: @user3482749 Ah, I see :) I should have specified that the functions must be defined on that set. Good remark.

Comment: @TheZone Yes, same thing. If for example $f$ is uniformly continuous on the union $(a,c)\cup(c,b)$ then both one sided limits at the point $c$ must exist and be equal.

Comment: @Mark thank you very much, my lecturer skipped through this section and didn't make these results clear.